# $C\subset R^n$ is closed then $\cup_{x\in C}\overline{B(x,\varepsilon)}$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

$V(C,\varepsilon) := \cup_{x\in C}\overline{B(x,\varepsilon)}$ where $C$ is closed so need to proof that $V(C,\varepsilon)$ is closed

Im taking a topology in $R^n$ class and basically the idea is to use the definitions of closed sets, closed balls to proof the above statement.

I would appreciate a hint, solution or guidance on how to proof this.

C is a closed set definition: $\forall (x_n)_n$ in $C$ converging sequence, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\in C.$

Comment: $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary but fixed positive number, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $d$ the distance on $\Bbb R^n$ which you used to define your closed balls.

Let $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ with $x_n\in V(C,\varepsilon).$ We shall prove that $x\in V(C,\varepsilon).$

Since $x_n\in V(C,\varepsilon),$ there exists $y_n\in C$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)\le\varepsilon.$

Since $(x_n)_n$ converges, it is bounded, hence so is $(y_n)_n,$ which therefore admits a converging subsequence $y_{n_k}\to y.$

Since $C$ is closed, $y\in C.$

And $d(x,y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})\le\varepsilon,$ which ends the proof.

Comment: Since the OP mentioned that this is a question about $\mathbb{R}^n$, they might not know what $d$ is. They might have only defined the norm $\|x\|$

Answer (score 0):

One can also prove that $V(C, \epsilon)$ equals $\{x \ | d (x, C) \le \epsilon\}$. Now here one needs to use the fact that for every $y \in X$ ( the total space), there exists $x \in C$ such that $d(x,y)$ is smallest. This might not happen in some spaces, even if $C$ is closed. It does work if say $X$ is locally compact ( like $\mathbb{R}^n$).